# Can't detect which li was hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Its quite simple to do and I have done it in past many times but I don't know why its not working now.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box" style="height: 50%;">
    <input type="search" class="input searchBox" placeholder="Search for items">
    <ul class="SearchResults clearfix"></ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
// SearchBox implementation
var searchBox = $(".searchBox").bind('keyup ', function () {

    var length = searchBox.val().length;

    if (searchBox.val().length > 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Invoice/GetProducts",
            type: "POST",
            data: { searchquery: searchBox.val() },
            success: function (result) {
                $(".SearchResults").append(result);
            }

        });
    } else {
        $(".SearchResults").empty();
    }

    //$(".SearchResults").text(searchBox.val().length);
});
```

and then this simple hovering code

```
$(".SearchResults li").hover(function () {            
    alert();
});
```

I have made sure that this script is running. li are added and everything but whatever I do I can't detect li hover, how ever it gives alert if I change the code to hover ul and not the li.

Comment: `$(".SearchResults li").hover(function () {

console.log(this);

});`

Comment: `this` inside the handler will refer to the hovered `li` element

Comment: You should delegate event to static UL container in order to handle event for dynamic elements

Comment: Li's are being created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for dynamically generated element and also use `this` in the event to get the element which is hovered.

```
$(".SearchResults").on('mouseenter', 'li', function () {
    alert(this);
})
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. So if I am adding elements dynamically I have to use event delegation ?

Comment: Yes. That's it. @Waleed

Comment: var li = $(this+" .name").text(); gives me error.

.name is a span inside each li

Comment: Try like this: `var li = $(".name", this).text()` @Waleed

Comment: This works too: 

    `var li = $(this);
    var name = li.children('.name').text();`